# Does a multicore cpu running Windows 10 64 bit speed up 32 bit programs?

Tags: cpu-usage

If Windows 10 uses multiple core cpu efficiently, will a 32 bit program work better because of the multiple core, or does the program have to be specially coded to utilize them?

Answer (score 1):

The program has to be specially coded to utilize more CPU cores, otherwise it will only use 1 CPU core like in every Windows version.